# Query documents by array value via Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get all posts which keywords property contains `req.query.keyword`.

Here is my try:

```
    router.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
    Post.find({"keywords" : { $in : [ req.query.keyword]  } } )
      .populate("author")
      .populate("comments")
      .exec((err, posts) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
          res.json(posts);
        }
      });
});
```

It returns just one element although there are more than one. Also how to query if there are more keywords ?

I'm sending the request with Postman: `http://localhost:3000/api/posts/?keyword=database`

Here is what I get:

```
[
    {
        "keywords": [
            "database",
            " mysql"
        ],
        "_id": "5b131352f495ad336408041e",
        "title": "MySQL",
        "body": "...
```

I should get one more document with

```
"keywords": [ "database",
              " mongodb" ] ...
```

Comment: Show documents you expect to match. You also have it the wrong way around as `$in` is for a "list of arguments" and not for "matching against a list field" as you seem to think it is. MongoDB does not care if `"keywords": req.query.keyword` is looking at a singular field or an array. It just matches whatever it matches.

Comment: Should you get it? Show us three documents. Two with the keyword to match and one without. In short ["show the reproducible case"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you don't get two documents with the same matching keyword. Because this works for the rest of the world, and as I already demonstrated you just don't even need `$in` for a "single" term.